# Excel - Merging Four Columns, if any cell has data

Tags: excel

I'm exporting a spreadsheet from a very disorganized database. There are four different zip code columns for whatever reason and many of the records only have one of the four columns filled in.

Lets say I have Zip1, Zip2, Zip3, Zip4

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

`if(zip !="", zip)` for each zip... and it can default to whichever cell actually has data. I'm not very great with Excel conditionals. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Say if your zip codes are spread across columns I, J, K and L starting in Row 1 maybe in M1:

```
=I1&J1&K1&L1
```

and copied down to suit. The columns might then be selected, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and ColumnsI:L then deleted.

Instead, assuming zip codes are strings, in case more than one column in any one row may have the same zip value:

```
=HLOOKUP("zzzz",I1:L1,1)
```